# Find all MongoDB documents from a list of ObjectIDs

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to find all documents from a MongoDB database, which has the ObjectID from my list of IDs with C#. Here's what I'm trying:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetFromIDs(List<string> productIDs)
{
    var client = new MongoClient(new MongoUrl("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
    var db = client.GetDatabase("Database");
    var products = db.GetCollection<Product>("Products")
        .Find(x => x._id == productIDs)
        .ToEnumerable();
    return products;
}
```

`productIDs` is simply a list of ObjectIDs from the MongoDB database. Obviously trying to find by a list of IDs doesn't work that way, as it takes a single parameter.

How do I `.Find()` all the documents from my list of product IDs?

Comment: unaware of C# but if were having a list like that, in mongo shell i would try $in.

Comment: @Avij Using `$in` does work, but I honestly don't know how to do it correctly. I'm trying this at the moment, but it's returning none because they're strings and not ObjectIds: `var filter = new BsonDocument("_id", new BsonDocument("$in", new BsonArray(productIDs)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the strongly-typed way.

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetFromIDs(List<string> productIDs)
{
    var client = new MongoClient(new MongoUrl("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
    var db = client.GetDatabase("Database");
    var productsCollection = db.GetCollection<Product>("Products");

    var productObjectIDs = productIDs.Select(id => new ObjectId(id));

    var filter = Builders<Product>.Filter
        .In(p => p.Id, productObjectIDs);

    var products = productsCollection
        .Find(filter)
        .ToEnumerable();

    return products;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is, the list parsed to `GetFromIDs` is of type `string`, whereas the `Id` on `Product` is of type `ObjectId`. Therefore I get an `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'FieldDefinition<Product, string>' because it is not a delegate type'.

Comment: No worries - your solution works just fine! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a pretty hacky solution. Not one of my proudest moments to be honest:

```
ObjectId[] allIDs = new ObjectId[productIDs.Count];

for(var i = 0; i < productIDs.Count; i++)
{
    allIDs[i] = new ObjectId(productIDs[i]);
}

var filter = new BsonDocument("_id", new BsonDocument("$in", new BsonArray(allIDs)));
var products = db.GetCollection<Product>("Products").Find(filter).ToEnumerable();
```

But hey, **it works**.