# Find all MongoDB documents from a list of ids using `in` operator

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

i am trying to find documents in collection by ids. Most of the suggested answers use  C# class that matches with the document. something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039455/find-all-mongodb-documents-from-a-list-of-objectids?rq=1)

```
var filter = Builders<Product>.Filter
    .In(p => p.Id, productObjectIDs);
```

i don't have corresponding C# class, so i am using `BsonDocument`

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<BsonDocument>> GetData(IEnumerable<int> documentIds)
{
    var collection = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("mycollection");

    // how do set filter here
    var filterBuilder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In<int>("???????", documentIds);

    var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection
       .Include("_id")
       .Include("status")
       .Include("units");

    var result = await collection.Find(filterBuilder).Project<BsonDocument>(projection).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return result;
}
```

I am not sure how do i set filter with `in` operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this filter:

```
var filter = new BsonDocument("_id", new BsonDocument("$in", new BsonArray(documetIds)));
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55417118/1257607)